# No response from SVN server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I make an svn commit, there is no response from the server although the commit goes through. I have tried performing the commit from different computers, and its the same issue, so it's not a problem on the client side. Do you know what could be the issue ?

Comment: Are you using a GUI or the command line? What exactly do you mean by, "there is no response"? E.g., if you are using the command-line client, do you mean that there is no, "Committed revision x." message?

Comment: Belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: There could be 1000 things which could cause this, we can't help you with this information

Comment: Its the same issue from the command line and the GUI, there is no response from the server saying "Commited revision ..." and due to this the NANT script which does the commit, keeps waiting for the response and fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get this message: "No response from Server", then in my opinion there is something wrong with the server. It happens sometimes when the Server is slow or it hangs, we get that message at client side. However, I believe the actual commit does not happen in the server.

Did you check the contents of the Server via a browser? See if the changes are being committed. On the other hand, if the URL doesn't open up, assume that its the problem with the server.

Comment: yes, the changes are being committed ! Am guessing the issue is on the server side too although restarting it does not seem to help and there is no processes overload on the server for it to hang or be slow.

Comment: Please check the post-commit hook if there is a bug in it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the commit goes through, you have a fine connection to the server.

Your problem seems to be with a post-commit hook script installed on the server: if such a script does not return, you won't get the final 'finished' response from the server.
The commit actually succeeds in these situations, but clients still show that the commit didn't go through. An update after the commit however then shows that the commit was done, or a 'show log' also shows the new revision.

So: first check whether the commit actually succeeded (using the log and/or update), and then check the server for post-commit hook scripts that don't work properly.

Comment: +1 for "post-commit hook".  I had the same problem.  Turns out I just forgot that I had stopped a CI job that was set to run post-commit.